# Combinatorics and Partitioning

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A class consists of 3 boys and 6 girls willing to form 3 groups of 3 called Group A, B, C.
How many ways are there to create groups such that every group includes 1 boy?
How many ways are there to create groups such that all three boys are in the same group?
How many ways are there to form groups such that one group has no boys?

For the first part, my idea is to count the number of ways to partition girls into 3 group of 2, then multiply by 3! for the number of ways the boys can fill the spaces. I'm not sure. 
(6!*3!)/(2!^3)

Comment: How many ways are there to ask you to show us some of your work_

Comment: This is a problem that we were asked to learn to solve by getting help from other people.

Comment: Great explanation of how and why you got the problem, @Virgo, yet I asked about what **you** have done so far.

Comment: For the first part, my idea is to count the number of ways to partition girls into 3 group of 2, then multiply by 3! for the number of ways the boys can fill the spaces. I'm not sure.

\frac{ 6! }{ 2!2!2! } * 3!

^^
Tried to use latex input

(6!*3!)(2!^3)

Comment: @DonAntonio Any hints or corrections?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you write without using LaTeX, but for the first part you only need to count the number of way you have to split 6 girls in three groups having exactly two girls in each, and in the second how to split the 6 girls in two groups with three in each...etc.

Comment: This is what I got:
(6!*3!) / (2!^3)

Comment: @DonAntonio After considering splitting the girls into groups of two, don't I have to multiply by 3! because the boys can fill in 3! ways, plus each group has distinct names, hence my answer.

Comment: I think you'd have to multiply by $\;3\;$ , without the factorial...

Comment: Let's see:
Say the groups A, B,C are already partially filled with 2 girls each.
The first boy has 3 choices, the second has 2, then the last has 1, hence the 3!
Just my thought; I might be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see: you distinguish between the boys. Ok then, I think.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming everyone has a different name and there are different groups. 
   With respect to my assumption, is my solution for the first part correct?

Comment: Looks like it is @Virgo but wait until someone else, with better eyes and better understanding of your typing, gives his/her opinion.

Comment: Okay, is there a way on here to format in latex or some good symbolic system?

Comment: Of course! We all use LaTeX (symbols between dollar signs). Enter any thread and click on "edit" to see the symbols and grammar used.

Comment: $\frac{ 6! }{ 2!2!2! } * 3!$

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Virgo: The expression $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}\times 3!$ is correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks a lot. Any hints on the other problems?

Comment: For $3$ boys, their group can be chosen in $3$ ways, the girls for the earliest in the alphabet unchosen label in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways, total $3\binom{6}{3}$.

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what I had in mind, though I used partitioning, and still got the same answer.
For the third part, I think Total  -n(1 group with three boys)-(each group with exactly three)
What do you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 boys, so according to the problem, each of them must go into a different group. If we consider Group A, Group B and Group C as being inflexibly named (for instance, the group is defined as being in a certain location), then there are 6 permutations of placing the three boys into the three groups, one each (1-2-3, 1-3-2, 2-1-3, 2-3-1, 3-1-2, 3-2-1). However, if the actual names of the groups are unimportant, such that we could say that Group A is always the group that has Boy 1 in it, Group B always has Boy 2, etc then no matter where you put all three boys, they define their groups, and so there's only one way to divide them up in a one-per-group manner.

Now for the girls. 2 girls out of a possible 6 can go into Group A. 6 nCr 2 = 15; there are 15 possible unique pairs of the 6 girls that can go in Group A (with order unimportant, it's combinations and not permutations that matters here). After taking any of those two girls for Group A, the number of combinations of the remaining 4 taken 2 at a time is 6. The last 2 girls go into Group C by default, and there's only one way to put them in. All of this is true regardless of the permutation of the boys' distribution, so each possible choice for each of these steps will yield a different unique grouping, therefore we must multiply the number of possible results for each step together.

So, 6 ways to put the boys in, times 15 ways to add a unique pair of girls to Group A, times 6 ways to put another unique pair in Group B, equals **540** unique ways to distribute these 9 children into independently-defined groups A, B, and C such that each group has a boy.

If the actual group names had been unimportant, and only their composition mattered, then there's only one way to distribute the boys, and so there are only 90 unique *combinations* of the actual children being split up that would have one boy each.

Comment: The boys, girls and groups have distinct names.

Comment: Using that constraint, how is the problem tackled?

Comment: You tackle it the same way.  In the first paragraph, there are $3!$ ways to assign the boys to the named groups.  The rest goes through the same, so the answer gets multiplied by $6$

Comment: It's a dubious testament to the difficulty of the logic in combinatorics problems that there are three answers to this question, each coming to a different result, and I found an error in mine, fixed it and am *still* not quite sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image: answer to the first part!]

firstly we can select one boy for one group in 3 ways. and for the second part we first make a group of three boys which we can make in one way. then the next group containing three girls out of 6 girls which can be done in 20 ways and the remaining third group in one way. so the total no of ways is 1+20+1 ie 22

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong with that image, @J

Comment: @Joy.. I don't think that'll work. This requires partitioning because the groups have names.

Comment: This looks as if the response was split between to answers. I will merged the answers. Let me know if this was not the proper thing to do.